# Describe explicitly the bijection between $2^\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N^\Bbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem from elementary set theory. I don't know, how to solve it and from what start.

How to describe explicitly the bijection between $2^\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N^\Bbb R$?

Comment: You don't need to exhibit an explicit bijection, injection in both directions is enough by [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), if you only want to prove they are [equipotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity). Do you really want an explicit bijection?

Comment: I have a task to describe an explicit bijection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a bijection between $2^{\mathbb Z}$ and ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb Z}$ by :

1. Let $(a_z)_{z\in\mathbb Z}$ an element of  ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb Z}$.
2. Define $b_z$ by :

   - Let $S_n=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(a_k+1)\right)-1$ for $n\ge 0$
   - Let $S_n=-\left(\sum_{k=n}^{-1}(a_k+1)\right)$ for $n<0$
   - Then for any $n\in \mathbb Z$ define $b_i=0$ if $\exists n, i=S_n$, otherwise $b_i=1$.

In fact it just encoding the sequence $a_z$ into unary separated by $0$s. So it's easy to verify that we just define a bijection that we now name $\Psi$. (So here $b_z=\Psi(a_z)$)

Example :
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}z&\dots&-4&-3&-2&-1&&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&\dots\\
\hline
a_z&&&&2&1&&1&2&0&3&\\
\hline
b_z&0&1&1&0&1&&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
\end{array}$$

So if you count the number of $1$s between each $0$s in $b_z$, you find back $a_z$. The origin point was chosen between $-1$ and $0$.

---

Now, an element $f$ of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb R}$ is just a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb N$.

It can be seen also as a function  $\phi$ from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb N^{\mathbb Z}$ such that $$\phi(x)= (z\mapsto f(z+x))$$
and ($x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$) 
$$f(x)=\phi(\{x\})(\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

By using the previous bijection on all $\phi(x)$, you obtain the bijection you want and the function $g$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\{0,1\}$ by :

$$g(x)=\Psi\left(\phi(\{x\})\right)(\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

Comment: Could you explain more about the function ϕ? I don't understand the last part of your answer and how we get connection between $2^z$ and $2^R$?

Comment: Ok, I add some details for the last part.

Comment: Nice, +1. So the last part uses a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb [0,1)\times \mathbb Z$ to obtain from a bijection $2^\mathbb Z\leftrightarrow \mathbb N^\mathbb Z$ a bijection $2^\mathbb R\leftrightarrow 2^{\mathbb Z\times[0,1)}\leftrightarrow \left(2^\mathbb Z\right)^{[0,1)}\leftrightarrow \left(\mathbb N^\mathbb Z\right)^{[0,1)}\leftrightarrow \mathbb N^{\mathbb Z\times[0,1)}\leftrightarrow\mathbb N^\mathbb R$.

Comment: Now I get the last part, but I tried to understand the first part about define b and I could not. Sorry for stupid questions, but what is Sn, what is n, what is sum for and why we do so?

Comment: I put an example, you just have to count the number of $1$s between the zeros in $b_z$…